# Installing pycopg2 gave me an issue

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-venv

I was able to install other pip libraries instead of pycopg2 when running this command - pip install psycopg2. I am using Azure Linux VM - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and have setup database configuration in settings.py.
Below is an issue:

> (venv) azureuser@signbank:~/projects/signbank$ pip install psycopg2
> Collecting psycopg2 Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/ae/98cb7a0cbb1d748ee547b058b14604bd0e9bf285a8e0cc5d148f8a8a952e/psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz
> Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2 Running setup.py
> bdist_wheel for psycopg2 ... error Complete output from command
> /home/azureuser/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-wzcbc8dl/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
> 'open', open)(__file
> __);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpnx61owb_pip-wheel- --python-tag
> cp36: usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
> or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...] or: -c --help-commands or: -c cmd --help
>
> error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
>
> Failed building wheel for psycopg2 Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
> Failed to build psycopg2 Installing collected packages: psycopg2
> Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error Complete output from
> command /home/azureuser/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-wzcbc8dl/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
> 'open', open)(fi le);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record
> /tmp/pip-nrmq1jq2-record/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --co mpile --install-headers /home/azureuser/venv/include/site/python3.6/psycopg2: running install
> running build running build_py creating build creating
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6 creating
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/extras.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/extensions.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/init.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/_ipaddress.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/pool.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/_json.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/tz.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/errors.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/_lru_cache.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/sql.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/errorcodes.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/compat.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 copying lib/_range.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 running build_ext building
> 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
> -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt d ec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100014 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/azureuser/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/10/server -c psycopg/psy copgmodule.c -o
> build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
> -Wdeclaration-after-statement unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
>
> It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from
> source.
>
> You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from
> PyPI. If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the
> packages required for the build and try again.
>
> For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file
> (also at https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html).
>
> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command "/home/azureuser/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-wzcbc8dl/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
> 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().repl ace('\r\n',
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record
> /tmp/pip-nrmq1jq2-record/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/azureuser/venv/include/site/python3.6/psycopg2" failed with
> error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wzcbc8dl/psycopg2/

or
picture here
[Installing pycopg2 issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq24v.png)

What could it possibly go wrong or did I miss something? I need your help.

Comment: `pip install psycopg2-binary`? as recommended in the failure?  (it looks like you are missing gcc? is the reason it couldnt build from source(at a guess))

Comment: Okay I see. I will try to install it later. Thanks boss

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing some dependencies. Can you try making sure that you have the following installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

and see if that helps.